# Possible to add rows to UITableView like iOS5 Weather app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there a way to add rows to a UITableView by tapping a row, then the table animating to display some 'hidden' rows of data? Much in the same way you can tap the nearest day in the iOS 5 weather app and show an hourly view of the weather?

Comment: To answer your question: yes there's a way, else the weather app wouldn't have done it. It would probably involve animating the UITableView or maybe even writing your own subclass of UIScrollView. I do not have any code for you though.

Answer (score 1):

How about the:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

method of the UITableView class?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, on a row press:

1. provide a different height for your row
2. tableView.beginUpdates
3. tableView.endUpdates

You'll need to implement a custom cell.  The hidden display elements should be already drawn in the custom cell.  When beginUpdates triggers tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: you should provide your updated height.  After endUpdates is called, this will cause the tableView to slide down your existing cell.