# The iOS weather app can scroll 'sub' table cells independantly of the 'main' table cells -- how is this done?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

The iOS weather app shows the forecast for each day of the week in a table.  If you tap a table cell, it expands to show a 'sub' cell containing a detailed forecast for that day.

How to do this was asked here: [Possible to add rows to UITableView like iOS5 Weather app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672127/possible-to-add-rows-to-uitableview-like-ios5-weather-app)  (Are there any other stack overflow questions that provide a better answer?)

If you scroll the 'expanded' table, the sub-cells scroll independently until there are no sub-cells left, then the whole table scrolls once more.

Question: How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I would guess that isn't a tableview at all. You have the weatherCard as parentView, lets say the *MainView*. At the top is the current weather and the first row of the "table" as static views. All the other rows are childs of another view (lets say the *DraggingView*), which has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. With that you control the dragging of the *DraggingView*.

Underneath the *DraggingView* there is the detailed TableView (lets say *DetailView*). This probably is a real tableView, just because of the sticking-header funcionality. But you could also easily do it with a standard scrollview.

So if you drag the *DraggingView* away, the *DetailView* gets visible. If it is scrolled to an offset of 0 again, the *DraggingView* gets layered on top again.

The resulting structure would be:

*MainView* 
* *DetailView* 
* *DraggingView*

And you would probably need an additional view, which masks the *DetailView* and the *DraggingView*. You enable that by using the `.clipsToBounds` property of `UIView`.